# Simplify does not simplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have this expression

```
Simplify[2 wb Z - 2 w xiR^4 Zb - 
  2 xiR^2 Sqrt[(wb Z - w xiR^4 Zb)^2/xiR^4]]
```

which is actually zero when just calculated by hand, with no assumptions needed...

But [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) just give the expression back within the brackets. Why is this?

Here in my case, `xiR`, `w`, `wb`, `Z` and `Zb` are complex-valued, `A` is real.

Comment: There is an implicit assumption you've made.  In particular, your simplification relies on `xiR \[Element] Reals` and an assumption about the positivity of `(wb Z - w xiR^4 Zb)`.

Answer (score 4):

```
Simplify[PowerExpand[
  2 wb Z - 2 w xiR^4 Zb - 2 xiR^2 Sqrt[(wb Z - w xiR^4 Zb)^2/xiR^4]]]

(*0*)
```